# Get top one record of difference date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to get just one record of last Order of everysingle customer. ATM I have this idea but it giving me all of them Date of orders.
I work on dataBase AdventurerWorks2012

```
SELECT
        H.CustomerID                   AS Customer,
        H.SalesOrderID                 AS OrderNumber,
        MAX(CAST(H.OrderDate AS DATE)) AS DateOrder
FROM
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader H
    JOIN
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail D
            ON H.SalesOrderID = D.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY
        H.CustomerID,
        H.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY
        CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

```
select top 1 with ties
*
From 
Sales.SalesOrderHeader H 
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail D
ON H.SalesOrderID = D.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by H.CustomerID order by H.OrderDate  desc)
```

This applies and ordering with `row_number()` giving each customer's order an ID starting at 1 and going to N based off the `OrderDate`. The `WITH TIES` allows us to return the `TOP 1` for each customer.

Another way, is using a `CTE`

```
;with cte as(
    select top 1 with ties
    *, RN =  row_number() over (partition by H.CustomerID order by H.OrderDate  desc)
    From 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader H 
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail D
    ON H.SalesOrderID = D.SalesOrderID)

select *
from cte
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do `JOIN`:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(h1.OrderDate) 
                   FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h1
                   WHERE h.CustomerID = h1.CustomerID 
                  );
```

By this you will get `customer`s with most recent order information.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 with ties
H.CustomerID AS Customer,
H.SalesOrderID as OrderNumber,
H.OrderDate As DataLast
From 
Sales.SalesOrderHeader H 
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail D
ON H.SalesOrderID = D.SalesOrderID
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by H.CustomerID order by H.OrderDate  desc)
```

This work like i need. Thanks!